# How to change the Color of the selected item in ListView in WinRT

Tags: winrt-xaml

I need to change the StackPanel background color for the item selected by user.

Apprecaite your help.

here my XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SpeechTemplate">

 <StackPanel x:Name="Sp" Width="400" Height="120" Background="Red">

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" 
                     Grid.Column="0"
                     Margin="3,3,0,0" 
                     TextWrapping="Wrap"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     FontSize="24"
                     FontWeight="SemiBold"/>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SId}" 
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     Margin="3,3,0,0" 
                     TextWrapping="Wrap"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     FontSize="18"/>

   <TextBlock Text="{Binding TopicId}" 
                      Grid.Column="2"
                      Margin="3,3,0,0" 
                      TextWrapping="Wrap"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      FontSize="18"/>

   </StackPanel>

 </DataTemplate>




<ListView x:Name="SpeechesGridView" Width="420"                               
                  Foreground="White"     
                  SelectionMode="None"
                  IsSwipeEnabled="True"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"

      ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource SpeechesViewSource}}"                      
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SpeechTemplate}"

      ItemClick="SpeechesGridView_ItemClick"      

      SelectionChanged="SpeechesGridView_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Override/add `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#YourColor" />` to your Application.Resources. You'll find all default colours in the generic.xaml file here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt\xaml\design (Assuming you work with x64).

Comment: it wont work on the StackPanel. It changes the color of the WORDS but NOT the StackPanel.

Comment: No, this would change the Foreground, ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush.

Comment: I did as per your instruction.Example:  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#000099"></SolidColorBrush> or Color="Blue". Do I need to do something on the ListView Control ?

Comment: Looks fine, where did you define it? On the page or as an application resource?